# Make use of Batch file as a projects application file and want to execute it through installshield

Tags: installshield

I want to use a batch file in my project's application files....but don't know how to make it executable through installshield......... please let me know if you have worked before on the similar situation.

Comment: Do you want to run the batch file as part of the installation process, or are you trying to install a batch file and turn it into an executable once the installation is complete?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to run a batch file as part of your installation process, you can probably find this information useful:

http://www.robertdickau.com/msi_tips.html#bat

Regards,

Juan Carlos